# SSMS 2008 Task List

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 there is a Task List very much like the one in Visual Studio, I can't seem to figure out how to put it to use nor can I find any documentation on it other than the documentation for Visual Studio which does not apply as the comment syntax is unique to TSQL...  The Task List in SSMS 2008 is accessible from the View menu, under Other Windows, Task List.   Using a solution with a query and adding a comment such as:

```
-- TODO: testing task list
```

or

```
/* TODO: testing task list */
```

does nothing.  Is this just some relic from the visual studio shell?   I was able to find a [feedback request for features](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=126635) for SSMS 2005 regarding a Task List to which there was a response that they were looking to put it into the next version (SSMS 2008)

Has anyone gotten this feature to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't find any way to add a task to this list in SSMS, just like I can't find any way to use the Output window that's also there. At first glance, it appears to be a holdover from Visual Studio, but that feature request you've found seems to dispute that and suggest that it actually has a use.

Even with a SQL Project open, I'm still not able to add a task, so I don't know that it's functional in 2008.